# running high end iterations in karate dsl

Tags: java, heap-memory, karate, heap-dump

While executing a scenario outline, I did not face any issues while executing low-end iterations on karate DSL for Data-Driven Testing using CSV input but as soon as the iterations started to cross a limit of 54, the error started popping up- Java.lang.outofmemory : Heap space error.

Looked for possible results but nothing was specific to karate dsl , they indicated towards memory leak or ini file, which is a temporary solution to change the Xms and XMx size, but it still didn't work.

Any other suggestion would be greatly appreciated, as the only java code in my script is either from DSL framework or my config or run file... During my heap memory analysis using jvisual, I was not able to identify any object which was causing a memory leak.... **I need to run 1600 iterations for assertion on DDT.**

Comment: use 1.2.0.RC6 and if you still find an issue, follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue